# Persisting a security token between calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-web-api

We are creating a prototype application as follows:

1. We have a html web site using knockoutjs
2. Using qQuery/Ajax it communicates with Web Api services

We only want the services to be accessed by authorised users. So we have written in security that can validate the user based on username/password

So next I guess we need to pass back some type of token to the client which it uses in further communications with the API services.

What I would like to know is how this is stored on the client so it can be passed back to the server again for the next call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the client makes an initial call passing in the user name and password over HTTPS and gets back a token. You question is to how to store the token? I assume your application is an SPA. If so, why not just store it in a JavaScript variable? If you do not use a cookie, you avoid XSRF. Of course, you must ensure the user name and password are never stored in the client side and that the life time token of your token is finite and preferably as small as possible.

EDIT:

If you can regenerate the token with every page (since it is not SPA), it is even better and you make the life time of token very small. You can use code like this. I use Authorization header and [bearer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) scheme but you can use your own scheme as well, if no standardization is needed.

```
var accessToken = ''; // Write out the token into this variable in the server side (view)

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://whatever',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    headers: { 'Authorization=': ='Bearer ' + accessToken },
    success: function (data) {
        
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the solution I was thinking of, but I haven't seen any examples of this anywhere. Everything will be over HTTPS, and the password is not sent or stored. The idea is that the token will have an expiry time which will be renewed with each call to the server

Comment: Its not a single page application, but I could pass the token when initialising the knockoutjs on each page

Comment: SPA stands for single page application (if someone is looking)

Answer (score 0):

> So we have written in security that can validate the user based on username/password

This sentence basically means that you need to store the username and password in your javascript file in order to be able to call the service, unless of course you want to ask the user to enter his credentials on every single action he performs. I hope this is not something you are wiling to do at the moment. If it is then you can stop reading my answer and store the username and password in your javascript file.

At this stage it is more than clear that your security should be handled differently. Your Web API should not be protected by a username and password but by a token. Here's how this could work in practice. You will have an action that will take the username and password, validate them and if successful it will return a token. This token could contain the encrypted username. So your javascript will ask the user for his username and password, call the Login method and it could store the token. Then it will use this token on subsequent calls. The API will in turn decrypt it in order to extract the username.

Comment: This is what we've done, after the initial authentication a token is passed back in the header of the response. What I want to know is how the client handles this in order to store and resend it in the next request

Comment: What do you mean by that? If by client you mean javascript then the token could be stored in-memory (a javascript variable?). If there are actions requiring to reload the current page, you could store the token in the browser session storage or even a cookie if you have to deal with some legacy browsers that don't support session storage.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to know is how this is stored on the client so it can be passed back to the server again for the next call?

Cookies. You will send token as a cookie, and it will be sent automatically when user requests your page.

Comment: Don't use a cookie sent to the server to identify the user.  Instead use a cookie only to store the token if you want to use it for future sessions. To identify the user, use a token passed in the request header.  Get the token from the cookie using javascript and send it in the header.

See: http://www.jamesward.com/2013/05/13/securing-single-page-apps-and-rest-services

Comment: @George Witte It seemed to me that the thing you say is useless, because in the end, you store token in cookie, and it can be stolen too.
Within token, storing encoded client info(IP, browser, OS information, etc.) and checking in the serverside whether the request made by same client is more secure and easy way I think.

Answer (score 0):

create a server side session, for the once authorised md5(username) md5(password). 
generate an uuid per request, and return it in the response. 
basic model is called token exchange and it is reliable (no m.i.t.m) even w/o SSL.